# Multiple websockets in one application

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Is it worth to create new websocket for new feature that should be real time or should i use one web socket connection for all thing?

My web app has some heavy data transfering ( e.g every few second users recieves/or sends data - it gets heavy with a lot of users ) , but some typical transfering like chat.

Should i use one web socket for both functionalities, or should i create new web socket connection for every "heavy" data oriented real-time functionality?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Define „heavy data“, “a lot of users” .. a few mb per second from 10 users or a few terabyte per minute from 10000 users? What do you think to accomplish using a second or third connection?

Comment: @dbf around 100 bytes per user to server and 100 bytes from server every second ( not counting chat ). And around million users.

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021380/1811956